# JPA Inheritance Type Joined - losing DTYPE on Merge

Tags: jpa, merge, persist

I have a super and subclass created which are using an inheritance type of JOINED.

On a persist, it all works...my DTYPE column in my superclass table is set to the class name "TravelTask".  However when I then try to do a merge, the DTYPE seems to get flushed to null.

I have tried, before doing a merge, to read back the persisted entity using entityManager.find() in a hope this pulls back the DTYPE value, but this is also being returned as null even though I can see it in the database....

So on a subsequent merge, the DTYPE is lost, and I then start to get primary key constraints (I assume this is related).

I have tried calling persist and merge from both the super and subclass, but the same thing happens...

Any advice appreciated.

i

Comment: I have to manually set the DType value to "TravelTask" any time I deal with the entity after an initial persist...or it gets Nulled out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you mapping the DTYPE column?  Normally you would not map this, JPA would just insert it based on the object's class.  It should never be updated.

Perhaps include your code, and JPA provider/version.